# How do I make Django signal handlers not fail silently when an exception is encountered in the signal handler?

Tags: python, django, error-handling

**How do I make Django signal handlers not fail silently** when an exception is encountered in the handler?

Is there **a place where all these errors are logged** while using **development server**?

Why do django signal handlers fail silently anyway? Isn't it against one of the lines in *Zen of Python*?

> ***Zen of Python*** clearly states...
>
> Errors should never pass silently.

It makes them a nightmare to debug. All you can see is that the signal is not getting fired...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511297/django-signals-fail-silently-any-better-way-of-debugging-mistakes) question but the answer is useless to me as it is very specific to the question (answer suggests using pyflakes, I already use pydev which does satisfactory static analysis)

Comment: if errors inside of your callback function are failing silently, why don't you unittest your callback function? all of the callback parameters can be easily mocked to ensure your callback function is error free

Comment: Can you make a testcase to reproduce this? I found that I got tracebacks from the development server with the following: http://pastie.org/private/tqd11vmhxvwgpxu65kixg

Comment: @dm03514 Unittests would be the way to go... but I would prefer if could get signal handlers to throw exceptions, so that even if some error prone case gets ignored while writing unittests, it is easily detected...

Comment: also if you want signals to not fail silently you could use send_robust instead() of send() if it is a custom signal. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.Signal.send_robust

Comment: The answer "write unittests" is not a good solution. If a unittest fail since an exception is silently ignored, you can waste hours to find the bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `manage.py shell` I get an uncaught exception when manually creating a FollowTable from your example. However, uncaught exceptions during a request don't show up in the terminal (other than showing that 500 was returned), instead they are shown in the browser. If you're using JavaScript to make requests you might want to look in firebug/chrome developer tools to see if it's returning a traceback.

Looks like someone else has answered how to get tracebacks to show in the console:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5886462/725359

Seemed to work for me. I did the following:

1. Added the `ExceptionLoggingMiddleware` class to `my_app/__init__.py`
2. Added `'my_app.ExceptionLoggingMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`
3. Restarted the development server

Comment: yup don't no what the problem was by restarting mysql and development sever solved it... thanks anyway..

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, errors should never fail silently

Yes, I think like you: errors should never fail silently

## Built in signals don't fail silently

Django's built in signals don't fail silently because they use `send()`

## Only `send_robust()` ignores exceptions

Docs from [send_robust()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.Signal.send_robust)

> send_robust() catches all errors derived from Python’s Exception class, and ensures all receivers are notified of the signal. If an error occurs, the error instance is returned in the tuple pair for the receiver that raised the error.

## Conclusion

Since django doesn't use `send_robust()` please investigate where it gets called. I guess it is in your source code, or in the code of a third party app.